# Issues with parallelizing processing of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, ray, charm++

I am having an issue with my attempt in speeding up the computation of my program. In the serialized python version of my code, I'm computing the values of a function f(x), which returns a float, for sliding windows of the NumPy array as can be seen below:

```
a = np.array([i for i in range(1, 10000000)]) # Some data here
N = 100
result = []
for i in range(N, len(a)):
    result.append(f(a[i - N:i]))
```

Since the NumPy array is really large and f(x) runtime is high, I've tried to apply multiprocessing to speed up my code. Through my research, I found that charm4py might be a great solution and it has a Pool feature, which breaks up an array in chunks and distributes work between spawned processes. I've implemented charm4py's multiprocessing example and then, translated it to my case:

```
# Split an array into subarrays for sequential processing (takes only 5 seconds)
a = np.array([a[i - N:i] for i in range(N, len(a))])
result = charm.pool.map(f, a, chunksize=512, ncores=-1)
# I'm running this code through "charmrun +p18 example.py"
```

The issue that I've encountered is that code was running a lot slower, despite being executed on a more powerful instance (18 physical cores vs 6 physical cores).

I've expected to see ~3x improvement, but it didn't happen. While searching for solutions I've learned that there is some overhead for expensive deserialization/spinning up new processes, but I am not sure if this is the case.

I would really appreciate any feedback or suggestions on how one can implement fast parallel processing of a NumPy array (assuming that function f(x) is not vectorized, takes a pretty long time to compute, and internally makes a large number of specific/individual calls that cannot be parallelized)?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried not making `a` into a numpy array, but just leave it as a list?  I suspect (but I'm not sure), that you may be repeatedly copying the entire numpy array into threads.  Something like a[3] still has the entire numpy array backing it.  charm.pool.map might not be smart enough to realize that every a[i] has the same backing array. . . . .  Worth a try.

Comment: Just using a predetermined size for `result` and indexing into it to store result of your function should speed this up a lot.

Comment: @FrankYellin, great idea. Haven't thought about that, but I am pretty sure that it's either this or too many processes being spawned. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help and time :)

Comment: @amzon-ex, thank you so much for your comment! How large of a performance increase are we expecting? I can imagine that creating a zero-like NumPy array and indexing it may reduce the number of memory-related operations. Is this thinking right? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to parallelize this operation with either Charm or Ray (it's not clear how you would use both together).

If you choose to use Ray, and your data is a numpy array, you can take advantage of [zero-copy reads](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serialization.html#numpy-arrays) to avoid any deserialization overhead.

You may want to optimize your sliding window function a bit, but it will likely look like this:

```
@ray.remote
def apply_rolling(f, arr, start, end, window_size):
    results_arr = []
    for i in range(start, end - window_size):
        results_arr.append(f(arr[i : i + windows_size])
    return np.array(results_arr)
```

note that this structure lets us call `f` multiple times within a single task (aka batching).

To use our function:

```
# Some small setup
big_arr = np.arange(10000000)
big_arr_ref = ray.put(big_arr)

batch_size = len(big_arr) // ray.available_resources()["CPU"]
window_size = 100

# Kick off our tasks
result_refs = []
for i in range(0, big_arr, batch_size):
    end_point = min(i + batch_size, len(big_arr))
    ref = apply_rolling.remote(f, big_arr_ref, i, end_point)
    result_refs.append(ref)


# Handle the results
flattened = []
for section in ray.get(result_refs):
    flattened.extend(section)
```

I'm sure you'll want to customize this code, but here are 2 important and nice properties that you'll likely want to maintain.

**Batching**: We're utilizing batching to avoid starting too many tasks. In any system, parallelizing incurs overhead, so we always want to be careful and make sure we don't start too many tasks. Furthermore, we are calculating `batch_size = len(big_arr) // ray.available_resources()["CPU"]` to make sure we use exactly the same number of batches as we have CPUs.

**Shared memory**: Since Ray's object store supports zero copy reads from numpy arrays, calling `ray.get` or reading from a numpy array is pretty much free (on a single machine where there are no network costs). There *is* some overhead in serializing/calling `ray.put` though, so this approach only calls `put` (the expensive operation) once, and `ray.get` (which is implicitly called) many times.

Tip: Be careful when passing arrays as parameters directly into remote functions. It will call `ray.put` multiple times, **even if you pass the same object**.

Comment: Excellent explanation and answer, Alex! Thank you so much for your time and help. I've resolved my issue by using joblib's Parallel method, but I will give your code a try to see if Ray performs better. Stay well :)

Comment: the way this is written i think you want to explicitly supply `window_size` param to `apply_rolling`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based off of your code snippet that uses [Ray](https://ray.io/) to parallelize the array computations.

Note that the best way to do this will depend on what your function `f` looks like.

```
import numpy as np
import ray
import time

ray.init()

N = 100000

a = np.arange(10**7)
a_id = ray.put(a)

@ray.remote
def f(array, index):
    # Do processing
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return 1

result_ids = []
for i in range(len(a) // N):
    result_ids.append(f.remote(a_id, i))

results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, Robert! I will give Ray a try.