# Processing numpy array in parallel significantly slows down process

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

For my work I have to process rather large numpy arrays (> 2e6 entries) by cutting them into small windows, and then calculating several features for each of those windows. To speed up this process I intended to take advantage of the multiprocessing-module. To test my approach, I wrote the following test code (applying a lowpass filter to each window):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
###########################################################################################
#
# test_vectorized_lowpass_filter.py
#
###########################################################################################
"""_summary_
"""
import time
from typing import Callable
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal


def apply_lowpass_filter(
    signal_window: np.ndarray, lowpass_frequency: float, sample_rate: int
) -> np.ndarray:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        signal_window (np.ndarray): _description_
        lowpass_frequency (float): _description_
        sample_rate (int): _description_

    Returns:
        _type_: _description_
    """
    lowpass_freq = lowpass_frequency / (sample_rate / 2)  # Normalize the frequency
    b_val, a_val = signal.butter(5, lowpass_freq, "low")
    lowpassfilter = signal.filtfilt(b_val, a_val, signal_window)
    return lowpassfilter


def generate_lowpass_filter(
    lowpass_frequency: float, sample_rate: int
) -> tuple[float, tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        lowpass_frequency (float): _description_
        sample_rate (int): _description_

    Returns:
        tuple[float, tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]: _description_
    """
    lowpass_freq = lowpass_frequency / (sample_rate / 2)
    return signal.butter(5, lowpass_freq, "low")


def apply_generated_lowpass_filter(
    signal_window: np.ndarray, filtfilt_vals: tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]
) -> np.ndarray:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        signal_window (np.ndarray): _description_
        filtfilt_vals (tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]): _description_

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: _description_
    """
    return signal.filtfilt(filtfilt_vals[0], filtfilt_vals[1], signal_window)


def unpacking_apply_along_axis(
    all_args,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        all_args (_type_): _description_

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: _description_
    """
    (func1d, axis, arr, args, kwargs) = all_args
    return np.apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)


def parallel_apply_along_axis(
    func1d: Callable, axis: int, arr: np.ndarray, *args, **kwargs
) -> np.ndarray:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        func1d (Callable): _description_
        axis (int): _description_
        arr (np.ndarray): _description_

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: _description_
    """
    effective_axis = 1 if axis == 0 else axis

    if effective_axis != axis:
        arr = arr.swapaxes(axis, effective_axis)

    # Chunks for the mapping (only a few chunks):
    chunks = [
        (func1d, effective_axis, sub_arr, args, kwargs)
        for sub_arr in np.array_split(
            arr,
            (
                multiprocessing.cpu_count()
                if multiprocessing.cpu_count() <= arr.shape[0]
                else arr.shape[0]
            ),
        )
    ]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(
        multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        if multiprocessing.cpu_count() <= arr.shape[0]
        else arr.shape[0]
    )
    individual_results = pool.map(unpacking_apply_along_axis, chunks)
    # Freeing the workers:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return np.concatenate(individual_results)


def test_vectorized_lowpass_filter() -> None:
    """_summary_"""
    lower_test_frequency = 10.0
    pass_frequency = 50.0
    window_size = 1000
    sampling_rate = int(1.25e6)
    time_vec = np.linspace(0, 2, sampling_rate, endpoint=False)
    lower_signal_vec = np.sin(2 * np.pi * lower_test_frequency * time_vec)
    filtered_lower_signal_vec = np.zeros(
        (int(len(lower_signal_vec) / window_size), window_size)
    )
    reshaped_test_frequency = np.reshape(
        lower_signal_vec,
        newshape=(int(len(lower_signal_vec) / window_size), window_size),
    )

    t_0 = time.time()
    for window_num, window in enumerate(reshaped_test_frequency):
        filtered_lower_signal_vec[window_num] = apply_lowpass_filter(
            signal_window=window,
            lowpass_frequency=pass_frequency,
            sample_rate=sampling_rate,
        )
    t_1 = time.time()
    ravelled_test_frequency = np.ravel(filtered_lower_signal_vec)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    t_2 = time.time()
    simple_test_frequency = apply_lowpass_filter(
        signal_window=lower_signal_vec,
        lowpass_frequency=pass_frequency,
        sample_rate=sampling_rate,
    )
    t_3 = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    t_4 = time.time()
    all_rows_test_frequency = np.apply_along_axis(
        apply_lowpass_filter,
        1,
        reshaped_test_frequency,
        lowpass_frequency=pass_frequency,
        sample_rate=sampling_rate,
    ).ravel()
    t_5 = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    t_6 = time.time()
    pregenerated_filt_data = generate_lowpass_filter(
        lowpass_frequency=pass_frequency, sample_rate=sampling_rate
    )
    all_rows_pregenerated_frequency = parallel_apply_along_axis(
        func1d=apply_generated_lowpass_filter,
        axis=1,
        arr=reshaped_test_frequency,
        filtfilt_vals=pregenerated_filt_data,
    ).ravel()
    t_7 = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    t_8 = time.time()
    all_rows_parallel_frequency = parallel_apply_along_axis(
        func1d=apply_lowpass_filter,
        axis=1,
        arr=reshaped_test_frequency,
        lowpass_frequency=pass_frequency,
        sample_rate=sampling_rate,
    ).ravel()
    t_9 = time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time for loop: {(t_1 - t_0)*10000}")
    print(f"Elapsed time for full window: {(t_3 - t_2)*10000}")
    print(f"Elapsed time for internal loop: {(t_5 - t_4)*10000}")
    print(f"Elapsed time for parallel loop: {(t_9 - t_8) * 10000}")
    print(f"Elapsed time for pregenerated parallel loop: {(t_7 - t_6) * 10000}")
    print(
        f"Data is equal: {np.allclose(a = ravelled_test_frequency, b = all_rows_test_frequency)}"
    )
    print(
        f"Data is equal: {np.allclose(a = ravelled_test_frequency, b = all_rows_pregenerated_frequency)}"
    )
    print(
        f"Data is equal: {np.allclose(a = ravelled_test_frequency, b = all_rows_parallel_frequency)}"
    )
    print(
        f"Shape of target data: {simple_test_frequency.shape}, shape of received data: {ravelled_test_frequency.shape}"
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_vectorized_lowpass_filter()
```

My output is:

```
Elapsed time for loop: 3431.6301345825195
Elapsed time for full window: 197.4964141845703
Elapsed time for internal loop: 3295.004367828369
Elapsed time for parallel loop: 35048.134326934814
Elapsed time for pregenerated parallel loop: 36795.69482803345
Data is equal: True
Data is equal: True
Data is equal: True
Shape of target data: (1250000,), shape of received data: (1250000,)
```

I.e. data is as expected, but the multiprocessing-approach takes significantly longer than the simple loop (which in turn is slower than just applying the lowpass on the entire data set at once).
What could be the issue here? Potentially the same as here: [Issues with parallelizing processing of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655998/issues-with-parallelizing-processing-of-numpy-array)? Or something else?

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` is not a performance tool.  In my experience it is slower than a simple loop.  It just streamlines (visually) the iteration when dealing with more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: Yes, therefore it's my benchmark. My parallel approach should be faster, but instead it is slower by a factor of ten...

Comment: @arc_lupus why *should* it be faster?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: My perhaps naive initial idea was to speed up the process by parallelizing it, i.e. distributing the work over multiple threads/cores, but apparently at least for the current problem the overhead is too big. Are there other approaches which could speed up my current problem?

Comment: From my (limited) experience with the filters of SciPy (specifically sos), I think they are quite slow, with a LOT of reshaping operations. Perhaps you could try with multithreading instead, it usually works better for me.